# Maximum triangle count in RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript

I wrote a quick application to get a feel for the limits of RenderScript and discoved that when reaching approximately 65,000 triangles, the system simply does not draw any additional ones. For example, if I create a cylinder with 70,000 triangles, there is a missing wedge from the cylinder corresponding to the triangles that exceed the ~65,000 count. The triangles are textured and for ease of writing the app, I simply used a `TriangleMeshBuilder` class so there is no real optimization going on such as using trifans or tristrips. The hardware is a Samsung Galaxy Nexus. LogCat reports a heap size of about 15MB with 3% free. I receive no errors or warnings regarding the graphics system or RenderScript.

Can anyone explain the reason for the triangles being dropped? Am I at a hardware limit that RenderScript is handling gracefully?

**UPDATE** Happens on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.0.3), Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0+ (3.2) and Motorola Xoom (3.2). All at the same point of approximately 65,000 triangles. Each of these devices have different GPU's.

**UPDATE 2** In response to Steve Blackwell's insights, I have some additional thoughts.

Lines 710-712 do indeed downcast the `int` indices to `short`, thus 65536 goes to 0 as Steve points out. Additionally, the "cast" on line 757 is not so much of a cast as telling the RenderScript the format of the binary data that will eventually be sent to it. RenderScript requires all data to be packed into a RenderScript specific data type called an `Allocation` to move from Java to the RenderScript runtime, and this needs to be informed as to the data structure. In line with Steve's opinion that this is a bug, line 757 informs RenderScript to treat the index data as `short` (unsigned 16bit) but it sends it a 32 bit signed value (which will be accepted due to the lack of a check and treated unsigned, and then only the lower 16 bits used, hence why we get something drawn when below this threshold and triangles connecting back to the first indices when we go over).

Subclassing `TriangleMeshBuilder` to see if I can make it accept these values all as integers to increase this limit did not work, which leads me to believe that somewhere in the deep code we do not have access to, there is an additional reference to unsigned shorts. Looks like the only work around  is to add additional vertex buffers as Steve suggests, which is easily done with the existing `Mesh.AllocationBuilder` class. I will also bring it up with Google in the Developer Hangouts to determine if this is in fact a bug or intentional.

Comment: Have you tried this on other devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know almost nothing about RenderScript, so I don't know whether this is some inherent limitation, a hardware issue, or something to do with TriangleMeshBuilder, but I would bet you're running out of triangles at after number 65535.

This is a magic number because it's the maximum value of an unsigned 16-bit integer. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types))

I would suspect that somewhere in the code there's an `unsigned short` that holds the number of triangles. It won't be in the Java code since Java doesn't have unsigned values. And the limitation is probably not hardware since CPU registers/pathways are >= 32-bit. So I would check TriangleMeshBuilder.

**EDIT:**

That's a great find on [line 553](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/renderscript/Mesh.java#553). The value of every index has to fit into a `short`. It looks like the downcast is happening at [line 710-712](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/renderscript/Mesh.java#710).

I assume that you're calling `addTriangle()`. That function takes three `int`s and then does an explicit cast to `short`. I think that's a bug right there because the downcast happens silently, and it's not what you'd expect from the function signature.

On [line 768](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/renderscript/Mesh.java#768), that bogus data gets passed to [`Allocation.copy1DRangeFromUnchecked()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/renderscript/Allocation.java#549). I didn't follow it all the way down, but I imagine that at some point, those signed values get cast to unsigned: the -32768 to -1 gets turned back into 32768 to 65535. So turning the indices into negatives looks bad, but it's just reinterpreting the same data and it's not really a problem.

The real problem starts when you send in values like 65536. When 65536 is cast to a `short`, it turns into 0. That's a real loss of data. Now you're referring to different indices, and a cast to unsigned doesn't fix it.

The real kicker is that `copy1DRangeFromUnchecked()` is an overloaded function, and one of the [overloads takes an `int[]`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/renderscript/Allocation.java#535), so none of this ever needed to be an issue.

For workarounds, I guess you could subclass `TriangleMeshBuilder` and override the member variable `mIndexData[]` and method `addTriangle()`. Or maybe you could use multiple vertex buffers. Or file a bug report someplace? Anyway, interesting problem.

Comment: It can't be in TriangleMeshBuilder because that is also Java, but since RenderScript is written in C99 it is likely that would be the case. I feel silly for not realizing I was near that threshold, especially since it ocured to me that I was below the 32 bit limit. I'll try to take a look into the C code and see if anything pops up.

Comment: I just took a look and the type definition for the relevant RenderScript data types and they all use unsigned 32 bit integers. Initially I would suspect (please correct me if I am wrong) that this is not the problem, however I have no way of looking at the actual source for RenderScript (just the header files).

Comment: I don't really know where to go from here. If you have code that you want to show or if you can point to an example you're using, that might help, but I'm a little out of my league with RenderScript.

Comment: The code for making the mesh in question can be found in my answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732813/how-to-make-a-cylinder-in-renderscript/10739884#10739884. For each "slice", you end up with 4 triangles. The short int limit then would be at 16384 slices. Unfortunately, until one of Google's RenderScript engineers chimes in, I have no way of knowing for sure if there is an unsigned short somewhere in the source of RenderScript.

Comment: Given that I have received no information from Google to the contrary and this seems like the most plausible reason for the problem (due to its hardware independence), I'm inclined to agree with you about the reason, so here is some more points for you. Thanks.

Comment: As an update, I found the line of code that limits to a short. It is actually in the Java code (contrary to my previous statement) for TriangleMeshBuilder. Line 553 of Mesh.java in API 14 uses a Java short to hold the index values. I understand it is unsigned so the limit should be 32,767, however, when passed to the RenderScript environment this signed short is treated as an unsigned short (line 757 of the same file)

Comment: Great find on line 553, but I'm not so sure there's a cast to unsigned on 757. See the edit for details on what I'm seeing. It's an interesting problem. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Steve, I have updated my post with some more details and response. Many thanks for your input on this. It drove me to look even deeper than I had and led to a better understanding of RenderScript under the hood which has actually solved a number of issues I was having on my current project. Please let me know if you think of or discover anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because OpenGL ES allows only `short` element indices, not `int`. Source: http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2.1:-Buffers-and-Textures.html (search for "OpenGL ES")